# Editing span text in wordpress?

Tags: html

Im trying to change the text in a span from "SOLD" to "SOLD OUT" in my wordpress website.

It looks like:

```
<span class="qode-pli-out-of-stock">SOLD<span/>
```

I am not too familiar with js, mostly css

Comment: You can write any text you like inside the span... Or do you need to do it conditionally? Via JS? ... Please add more infos.

Comment: The HTML you show is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to find all the spans with the `qode-pli-out-of-stock` class and change their text.

```js
for (var elem of document.querySelectorAll('.qode-pli-out-of-stock')) {
    elem.innerHTML = 'SOLD OUT';
}
```

```html
Example <span class="qode-pli-out-of-stock">SOLD</span> and another <span class="qode-pli-out-of-stock">SOLD</span>.
```

Comment: This worked but I read somewhere that using innerHTML can make you vulnerable to XSS attacks?

Comment: @JohnDoberneck it can make you vulnerable if you allow user-entered data - all user-entered data should be considered malicious, not just into your JavaScript, but into your HTML. As you have hard-coded the value, this shouldn't be an issue.